# Angular directive doesn't update model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, updates, angular-ngmodel

Hello I am trying to update my model from a directive but it does'nt work. I can't find Why. Can someone help?

Html:

```
<input type="file" name="documents" file-model ng-model="documents"multiple>
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" ng-click="loadDocuments()">
```

Directive:

```
app.directive("fileModel", ["$parse",function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require:"ngModel",
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;
            element.bind("change", function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.ngModel = element[0].files;
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Result:

`$scope.documents={};
$scope.loadDocuments = function () {
        console.log($scope.documents); //PRINT UNDEFINED
    }`

Comment: `console.log($scope.ngModel)`

Comment: should always have an object in `ng-model`. Your binding may be being broken by child scopes

Comment: I don't really understand the concept of childscope... I first created my var as this: $scope.documents={};

Comment: @Roy.23's solution works. Try again and see https://jsbin.com/pakixatuju/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
app.directive("fileModel", ["$parse",function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;
            element.bind("change", function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);



<input type="file" name="documents" file-model="documents" multiple>
```

Comment: Thank u Roy but it was the first thing i tryed. i had the same result.

Comment: Check this out:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/878730/File-Upload-Using-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: yes it is the tuto I am following. but my directive does not update the model. so I change it to what I have posted.

Comment: could you pls now try this way??

Comment: It definitely works. see https://jsbin.com/pakixatuju/1/edit?html,js,console,output